# What font in mathmode gives the "T" used here to denote a Hausdorff space on Wikipedia?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space) (also in textbooks) for a Hausdorff space, you see that notation for (in mathmode) "$T_2$" being used. However, as you can see in the screenshot, it is very "straight" as opposed to italicized-looking:

[image]

I tried googling what it is, and also tried detexify but couldn't get a result. What font is this in mathmode? \mathrm didn't seem to give it to me.

Comment: `$\mathsf{T}_2$`? This doesn't look any special to me. Just an upright, sans serif T. And sans-serif is just because Wikipedia's font is just that, I don't think that's an explicit choice. (It's also bold but that's emphasis.) See also [*Trennungsaxiom*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom).

Comment: The style is sans serif, and `\mathsf{T}` seems to be the appropriate input.  In the Wikipedia article cited, the letter is set in bold when emphasis is needed, but from context, lightface sans appears to be the proper presentation for ordinary use.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The notation does seem to be special, in that it appears in "Topology Without Tears" by Sidney. A. Morris. This is where I first saw the notation being used, before the Wikipedia article. Perhaps he copied the notation from Wikipedia though, haha.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That seems to be perfect, and correctly matches the notation. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nate Don't look too much into notation used by some author or, generically, book or website. In some cases, a particular notation catches on, such as ℝ for the real numbers; but it's far from being universal and was much less used than today just a couple of decades ago. If you write T with a subscript, whatever kind of typographic T you employ, any topologist would know from the context if you're referring to some separation axiom. A typographically distinctive notation (such as `\mathsf{T}`) is needed if you happen to use a subscripted T in different contexts.